# Any update on our graduation?

Tags: discussion, graduation

**This is more specifically a question for the mods.**

Now that we have a very impressive set of stats (we've been having them since a couple of months now): http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/55053/data-science, would we be considered for graduation soon?

If yes, then how soon and what is the procedure for the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know who decides that or flips the bit. There are five criteria there that this SE mostly meets; I don't know if they're hard requirements. I think there's enough interest to sustain the SE, so, seems logical to move it out of beta eventually. For now, think just keep growing.

Comment: These days I believe the key criterion is 10 questions per day consistently, although I can't remember where I've heard that.

Comment: @DavidZ Yeah, I remember seeing that too. Maybe in some Meta post. Don't remember :)

Comment: [Helpful Reference](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/257614/302377) :)

Comment: @DavidZ I think this is the [place](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/55053/data-science) where you had seen that criterion

Answer (score -1):

I think that these area51 statistics are one thing, but one should also consider the significant overlap with  http://stats.stackexchange.com. If amongst the ~12 daily questions that Data Science receives, half of it is on-topic on http://stats.stackexchange.com, this makes the graduation of Data Science less attractive.